# Current branch is behind its remote counterpart

Tags: git, git-branch

I‘m really new to git, we have a simple project with a single branch, but at some point I decided to delete my local project folder and created a new one.
Now I want to push it to that single branch, and it tells me the tip of current branch is behind its remote counterpart!
What should I do? I needed to write the project a new and want to clear the branch as if it was created a new on the remote

Answer (score 0):

> “the tip of your current branch is behind its remote counterpart”

...means that there have been changes on the remote branch that you don’t have locally.

As an example, let’s say that you have created a local branch named `my-feature`.

```
$ git branch
  master
* my-feature
  feature
```

However, you want to push your changes to the remote branch named “feature” on your repository.

In order to push your branch to another branch, you may need to merge the remote branch to your current local branch.

In order to be merged, the tip of the remote branch cannot be behind the branch you are trying to push.

Before pushing, make sure to pull the changes from the remote branch and integrate them with your current local branch.

In order to push your branch (`my-feature`) to the `feature` branch, you would execute the following command:

```
$ git pull
$ git checkout my-feature
$ git merge origin/feature
$ git push origin my-feature:feature
```

> Note : when merging the remote branch, you are merging your local branch with the upstream branch of your local repository.